# UIStoryboardSegueTemplate Undefined

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get all the Segues attached into a UIViewController. Some of them are custom Segues

So far I have done:

```
let array = value(forKey: "storyboardSegueTemplates") as! [Any]
for item in array{
    print(String(describing: item.self))
    if let segueItem = item as? UIStoryboardSegueTemplate {
        print("CUstom Segue")
    }
}
```

but UIStoryboardSegueTemplate is not found.

Comment: Why do you need to get all the segue of a view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want get the identifier you can use this:

```
guard let array = self.value(forKey: "storyboardSegueTemplates") as? [AnyObject] else {
    //No segues
    return
}

for item in array{
    print(String(describing: item.self))
    print(String(describing: item.value(forKey: "identifier")))
}
```

Comment: Thats is correct! Thank you. I have found this link https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIStoryboardSegueTemplate.h and i have an idea of what key I might get. Although There is a destinationId as string, i can get it as UIViewController. Only if the id is set.

Answer (score 0):

**the class `UIStoryboardSegueTemplate` is private to apple and your swift compiler doesnt know it.**

> you cant use the private class as you dont have the header for it.
>   Access the object using KVC or using reflection in that case!